# socket.io source code for GWT

Tags: gwt, socket.io, libgdx

Im making a multiplayer game with GDX. it works on desktop/android but when I want to compile it with GWT I get this Error:

```
[ERROR] Line 24: No source code is available for type io.socket.client.Socket; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 69: No source code is available for type io.socket.client.IO; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      [ERROR] Line 79: No source code is available for type io.socket.emitter.Emitter.Listener; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io is not compatible with GWT. Consider using a different framework, such like [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).